# Sort and format in email

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm new to Powershell and I'm trying to send the output by email of the following piece of code, if I send it to the console, it is formatted nicely, but when I pipeline it into an email, the retrieved objects are not lined up.

```
$bios = Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS -ComputerName localhost
$os = Get-WmiObject `Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName localhost
$Proc = Get-WmiObject Win32_processor -ComputerName localhost | Select-Object -First 1
$memory = Get-WmiObject Win32_physicalmemory -ComputerName localhost
$system = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName localhost

$Systeminfo = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
'ComputerName' = $proc.SystemName;
'Manufacturer' = $bios.Manufacturer;
'Model' = $system.Model;
'BIOS Version' = $bios.Version;
'Serial Number' = $bios.SerialNumber;
'Number of Processors ' = $system.NumberOfProcessors;
'Processor Name' = $proc.name;
'Logical Processor' = $system.NumberOfLogicalProcessors;
'Speed (MHZ)' = $proc.CurrentClockSpeed;
'RAM (GB)' = $system.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB -as [int];
'Used RAM slots' = $memory.count;
'OSVersion' = $os.Caption
}
$Systeminfo = $Systeminfo | Out-String
```

Also, is there a way to rearrange the order they appear, for example, I would like the computername to be first in the array, but it appears in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have PowerShell 3.0 you could create the object using [`[ordered]`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847780.aspx)

```
$Systeminfo = [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
'ComputerName' = $proc.SystemName;
'Manufacturer' = $bios.Manufacturer;
'Model' = $system.Model;
'BIOS Version' = $bios.Version;
'Serial Number' = $bios.SerialNumber;
'Number of Processors ' = $system.NumberOfProcessors;
'Processor Name' = $proc.name;
'Logical Processor' = $system.NumberOfLogicalProcessors;
'Speed (MHZ)' = $proc.CurrentClockSpeed;
'RAM (GB)' = $system.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB -as [int];
'Used RAM slots' = $memory.count;
'OSVersion' = $os.Caption
}
```

That should output the properties in the order they were defined. Else you would need to use a `select` statement to order the properties that you want.

```
$Systeminfo | Select-Object ComputerName,Manufacturer,Model,"BIOS Version","Serial Number","Number of Processors","Processor Name","Logical Processor","Speed (MHZ)","RAM (GB)","Used RAM slots",OSVersion
```